# Ctypes DLL call ArgumentError with c_char_Array

Tags: python, typeerror, ctypes

i'm trying to write a Python DLL Wrapper for a C Project

- https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM -> C Project
- The Python DLL Wrapper can be found here: 
  https://github.com/GitHubStefan13/SOEM-for-Python

Original C Code that is important:

1. `char IOmap[4096];`
2. `int ec_config_overlap(uint8 usetable, void *pIOmap);`

Python Wrapper

1. `IOMap = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char * 4096)`
2. `c_ec_config_overlap = ethercat.ec_config_overlap
   c_ec_config_overlap.argtypes = [ctypes.c_unit8, IOMap] 
   c_ec_config_overlap.restype = ctypes.c_int`

When im trying to define a function in Python

`def ec_config_overlap(usetable, PIOMap): 
    return c_ec_config_overlap(usetable, PIOMap`

and call it.
I receive the error

> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: : expected LPc_char_Array_4096 instance instead of _ctypes.PyPointerType.

I understand the Error but how do i go around to actually make the ctype a Array[4096] instead of the PyPointerType?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax creates array instances:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> (ctypes.c_char*4096)()
<__main__.c_char_Array_4096 object at 0x0000024D84E2D7C8>
```

Since it is a `char` array, you can also use:

```
>>> create_string_buffer(4096)
<__main__.c_char_Array_4096 object at 0x0000025AE48FE948>
```

The type of your function should be:

```
c_ec_config_overlap.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint8, ctypes.c_void_p]
```

But for better type checking you can also use:

```
c_ec_config_overlap.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint8, ctypes.c_char_p]
```

Comment: Right the ctypes.c_void_p was the right way, dunno how i oversaw that.
Sadly it still does not work though, everytime i try to call the function i now get the same error but simply stating "wrong type". The type checking with c_char_p does not work either.

Comment: @Stefan Update your question with your attempt and new error message.  I took a look at the GitHub source and the `soem.IOMap` is a type not an instance.  See my first example above.  It is important to put your code as a [mcve] and not a link to the full source.